# Difficulty in a Fubini's Theorem Question

Tags: integration, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Let $f(x)$ be integrable and non-negative. Let $\int_{-\infty} ^\infty f(x)dx = 1$.

Now, let $g$ be a bounded measurable function and let $G(y) = \int_{g(x)≤y} f(x) dx$.

I want to show that $\int_0^{\infty}(1-G(y)-G(-y))dy = \int_{-\infty} ^\infty f(x)g(x)dx$. My initial idea was to separate the integrand into $1-G(y)$ and $G(-y)$ to apply Fubini, but I didn't manage to make it work. Is that the way to do it or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $$1 - G(y) - G(-y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) (1 - 1_{g(x) \le y} - 1_{g(x) \le -y}) \, dx.$$

If you are able to justify the interchange of the double integral via Fubini's theorem, then
$$\int_0^\infty (1-G(y)-G(-y)) \, dy
= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \int_0^\infty (1 - 1_{g(x) \le y} - 1_{g(x) \le -y}) \, dy \, dx.$$

It remains to show the inner integral equals $g(x)$. To do so, check that
the integrand of the inner integral is
$$1 - 1_{g(x) \le y} - 1_{g(x) \le -y}
= \begin{cases}
1 & g(x) > y
\\
0 & - y < g(x) \le y
\\
-1 & g(x) \le -y
\end{cases}$$
and check that the integral of this over $y \in [0, \infty)$ is $g(x)$.

Comment: Very nice solution, thank you!